# Huffman Code with Weight

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I am trying to construct a Huffman tree with the symbols $A, B, C, D, E$ with the weights $1, 1.5, 3.1, 3.7, 2.2$.

Now from looking at [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) I order the symbols based on the highest weight like this $D 3.7, C 3.1, E 2.2, B 1.5, A 1$ and paired the lowest weight together.

This is what I constructed and I am looking for feedback I am not sure if it should be the other way around where the lowest weight should be placed first.

[image]

Comment: If you are asking about the labeling/ordering of the symbols, i.e., whether you should have used $ A:3.7, \ldots, D:1$ it's irrelevant. The same expected codeword results.

Comment: Obviously, the Huffman algorithm can be used to either maximize or minimize the average weight [usually minimization is of interest due to the weight being the probability of the symbol]. You should clarify your question

Comment: I created the tree with minimizing the weight in mind but not sure if it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the OP has now specified they created the tree to minimize the expected weight, I'm entering this answer:

This is a valid Huffman tree, minimizing the expected path weight.